ASP.NET Core MVC with React Integration not finding my bundle.js on Production Server [Azure]
My code working fine on localhost but when I deploy to production, it is unable to find bundle.js:
enter image description here
It's perfectly working in development mode:
enter image description here
When I analyse it, I see these differences:
On localhost:
enter image description here
but in production dist and other jsx folder is not there:
enter image description here
Here is my folder structure [ASP.NET Core 6]:
enter image description here
This is my .cshtml markup:
cshtml
I am using Docker to publish so here is my docker file:
docker
I don't know what and where I am doing wrong, because it is running on localhost without any issue. But it fails on the production server.
Thanks in advance for any help

After lot's of try I got Solution
the problem was in docker file so I changed and now working fine
here is the change
 FROM node:18 as buildjs
 WORKDIR /app
 ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 COPY " reactApp/" ./reactApp
 COPY " package.json" ./
 COPY " package-lock.json" ./ 


 RUN npm install --silent
 RUN npm install react-scripts@5.0.1 -g --silent
 RUN npm run wpb  #this is my webpack run command in package.json



FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=buildjs /app/dist ./wwwroot/dist

